# how to dynamically render multiple form elements using for loop

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop, show-hide

i want to display a certain number of input tags for a form; this should depend on how many items a user dynamically selects that they want.

for example, if a user says they want 3 items. i want to display 3 input bars.

i am not clear of the best way to proceed with this. for example, i am able to determine how many items they select from the select options:

```
 $(".howmany").change(function(){

            var value  = $(this).val(); 

}
```

but what is the correct way to proceed thereafter; do i dynamically render the exact number of input tags selected using a **for each**: or pre-display (but hide) all of the input tags and only show the exact number of input tags requested.

i would appreciate an example of how its been done . at the moment i am only able to hide the entire area. eg:

```
var requests =  $("#howmany").val();

        if (reqeusts < 1){
            $('#reqeusts').hide();
        }
        else {
           $('#reqeusts').show();
       }
```

but i obviously need to be able to show individual form tags accordingly to the number the user selected.

hi again,  i want to thank everyone for their answers.

i deeply sorry, but i forgot to mention that the reason for the confusion is that the values for the imput are dynamically fed from an array function.

```
public function arrayValues() 
                    {
                        return $selection = array(
                            '0' => 'none' ,' 1' => '1 item' ,' 2' => '2 item' ,' 3' =>' 3 item' );
                    }
```

i then need to render one of the below imput select tags for each number of items selected.

```
                    <?php echo ' 
                    <select id="howmany" name="items[howmany]"  />'; 


                    foreach ($arrayValues as $key => $value)
                    {       
                        echo '<option value="' . $key .'">' . $value . '</option>';
                    }
                    echo'</select>'; 
                    ?>
```

Comment: _but i obviously need to be able to show individual form tags accordingly to the number the user selected._ Not true. You'll need a single `form` with a variable number of `inputs`.

Comment: A simple `for loop` appending `inputs` would solve your problem just fine.

Comment: hi MelancialUk. thank you for your response. i think the issues is more complicated than a simple for loop. i did not give the full issues in the question. i apologize for the error. the input tags that need to be dynamically rendered are select tags that depend on array values being fed to them. i have amended my original question. i would also ask that my question not be downloaded. i think it is a complex question

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".howmany").change(function(){

            var value  = $(this).val(); // get the number of inputs
            value = parseInt(value); // make sure it's an integer
            htmlStr = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < value; i++)
            {
                  htmlStr += "Label " + i +" <input type='text'>";
            }

            $('.container').empty();
            $('.container').append(htmlStr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').empty().append(new Array(+$('input[type=number]').val()+1)
   .join("<input type='text' placeholder='Type Something'/>"));
});
```

I hope this gives you an idea of how to solve your problem.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/stymeyw8/)

Comment: hi Amit. thank you so much for your help. i am looking at it now. i forgot to mention that i needed to feed the imput tag with array values. i have corrected my question above. i think the issue now is how to feed those array values into your equation